# Ninject InRequestScope missing

Tags: c#, binding, ninject, ninject-2

Have a couple of questions regarding the latest version (2.2.1.4) of ninject.

Was trying to Bind a Linq2sql `DataContext` to a concrete implementation `InRequestScope` (in a class library project)

```
Bind<DataContext>().To<MoneywatchDataContext>()
```

but could not find `InRequestScope` method

[image]

ended up doing this,

```
Bind<DataContext>().To<MoneywatchDataContext>().InScope(ctx => HttpContext.Current)
```

Just wanted to find out if:

1. If this will behave exactly like the `InRequestScope` Method.
2. That it will gurantee that when my `HTTContext.Current` is GC'ed the underlying `DataCotext` will be disposed as well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Most likely you reference a no web version of Ninject. Replace it with the normal version and you will have the InRequestScope extension method.

Answer (score 50):

InRequestScope is available as extension method in Ninject.Web.Common. So if installed earlier through Nuget (Ninject package) now we might need to install additional nuget package Ninject.Web.Common

Comment: Remeber that you need to install this package on the project that your module class is being configured. I had a problem in which I have installed it in the MVC project but the module where I put `Bind<>().To<>().InRequestScope();` was in the Infrastucure project. I took me a while to realize that.

Comment: That was it! Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

```
using Ninject.Web.Common;    // that's most likely all you need
```

Comment: This is the actual answer that helped me.

Comment: (this imports the namespace containing the extension method)