# What happened To Ninject's InRequestScope

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, nuget, nuget-package

I started a new project today and went to nuget to get ninject.

I downloaded the [Ninject MVC3](http://nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC3) plugin that should download everything else I need.

I then took some old code from a different project and noticed that InRequestScope seems to be gone.

Was it taken out or am I missing something?

**Edit**

I think I found it under "Ninject.Web.Common"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ninject v2.2.1.4 InRequestScope missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911894/ninject-v2-2-1-4-inrequestscope-missing)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This extension method is defined inside the [`RequestScopeExtensionMethod`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web.Common/RequestScopeExtensionMethod.cs) class inside the `Ninject.Web.Common` assembly [which is in a NuGet package with the same name]. This assembly (/package) is automatically referenced when you install the `Ninject.NVC3` NuGet package. In order to use it, you need to bring the `Ninject.Web.Common` namespace in scope:

```
using Ninject.Web.Common;
```

Comment: Remeber that you need to install this on the project that your module class is being configured. I had a problem in which I have it installed in the MVC project but the module where I put `Bind<>().To<>().InRequestScope();` was in the Infrastucure project. I took me a while to realize that.